# Status of spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka

Tags: spring-cloud-netflix

Eureka Service Discovery Server and Client was developed by Netflix. But Netflix has stopped updating Eureka. Thus, I'd like to know what is the impact to spring-cloud-netflix-eureka.
Does it mean there will be no more features added to the project?
But I found both spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client and spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-server is still active.
Or those are just bug and security fixed.
Appreciate for any replay.

For better understand the status of the project.

Answer (score 0):

Eureka is still under development by Netflix with contributions by the Spring Cloud team. `2.0.1` was released in June and we fully expect for the releases to continue - no downtime date has been announced. In keeping with this, no maintenance mode or planned downtime has been announced for Spring Cloud Netflix Eureka projects either. The project is mostly stable and seems to cover the users needs, so we fix bugs more often than add enhancements, but there's no reason enhancements would not be added if gaps for valid usecases are identified.